# Petición ajax 404

Tags: javascript, ajax, vue.js

estoy haciendo un lista de personajes en vue y cuando tomo la llamada con Ajax me dice que no lo encuentra, es decir,

Este es mi script

```
<script>
    export default {
        name: 'place',
        data()
        {
            return {
                place: {}
            }
        },
        created()
        {
            var vm= this;
            var id = this.$route.params.id;
            //console.log(id);
            axios.get('https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/people/${id}/?format=json').then(function(response){
                vm.place = response.data;
                console.log(vm.place);
            })
        }

    }



</script>
```

y tengo error con la llamada ajax

```
axios.get('https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/people/${id}/?format=json').
```

me dice 404 que no la encuentra, pero antes estoy buscando la id

```
var vm= this;
            var id = this.$route.params.id;
            console.log(id);
```

y efectivamente me da la id

y si el numero lo remplazo en `https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/people/r6Je/?format=json` efectivamente existe.

pero al pasarlo como variable

```
'https://adventuretimeapi.herokuapp.com/people/${id}/?format=json'
```

me dice que no lo encuentra, ¿Esto por qué puede ser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás usando un string normal, cuando deberías usar un *string template*:

Un string en Javascript está delimitado por comillas simples o dobles, mientras que el string template, que admite variables (o una expresión) con el formato `${<expresión>}`, usa comillas inversas (`) :

```js
var test=24;

console.log("String normal: ${test}")
console.log('String normal: ${test}')
console.log(`String template: ${test}`)
```